# How to call a NestJs micro-service from an EventEmitter listener function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, microservices, nestjs

I'm developing two micro-services with NestJS and typescript for consuming and publishing messages on two different queues. The scenario is as follows

1. A consumer micro-service reads messages from a Kafka topic or queue
2. Then it sends this message to second micro-service.

The problem appears on the second step, the message is never sent by the consumer micro-service.

---

The message consumption is implemented with `Consumer` from library `kafka-node`. The messages are consumed correctly and can be logged.

The communication between micro-services is made with `RedisClient` from package `@nestjs/microservices` and is working when performed from outside the listener method.

When the messages between micro-services are sent from anywhere else I can see them on the `redis-cli MONITOR`, but when sent from the listener function nothing appears.

#### Code

Redis client and Kafka consumer initalization:

```
private readonly kafkaClient: kafka.KafkaClient;
private readonly consumer: kafka.Consumer;
private readonly client: ClientRedis;

constructor() {
    this.kafkaClient = new kafka.KafkaClient(KAFKA_HOST);
    this.consumer = new kafka.Consumer(this.kafkaClient, TOPICS, OPTIONS);
    this.client = new RedisClient(REDIS_URL);
}
```

The listener function for consuming messages is:

```
async onApplicationBootstrap() {
    this.consumer.on('message', message => {
        // Sends the message to Redis
        this.client.send<Message>(PATTERN, message);
    });
}
```

Then the second microservice should get the message thanks to the `@MessagePattern(PATTERN)` NestJS' decorator. But it's not even being published on Redis as I said previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the problem was with the `Observable` returned by `ClientRedis::send()` method. Just converting the `Observable` to `Promise` solved the problem:

```
  this.client.send<Message>(PATTERN, message).toPromise()
```